# Running npm command within Visual Studio Code

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code

Is there anyway of executing the `npm` command within Visual Studio Code (using `f1` into `>`) on Windows(10) to install packages to my folder I'm working in?

I have npm installed and I keep having to install npm packages from `cmd`

Answer (score 115, accepted):

**Install**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, write `ext install npm script runner`
- Restart VS Code

**Use** (two ways)

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, write `>npm`, select `run script`, select the desired task

---

**Update**: Since version 1.3 Visual Studio Code has integrated terminal. To open it, use any of these methods:

- Use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> keyboard shortcut.
- Use the View | Toggle Integrated Terminal menu command.
- From the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>), use the `View:Toggle Integrated Terminal` command.

Comment: On french keyboard: 
 "Use the Ctrl+` keyboard shortcut."
becomes
 "Ctrl+ù"

Comment: On Mac, use 'Cmd+R Shift+R'

Comment: Please give a link to the extension from the market. I did not find such an extension. It does not exist.

Comment: @dev-siberia there is no need of any extension since the 1.3 version. Just follow the instructions described in the answer for the update. Ctrl + `

Comment: Note: if you're launching VS Code from the Anaconda Navigator, you'll need to restart the navigator as well.

Comment: Its Deprecated now. No Longer Supported.

Comment: I am running VS Code 1.8, and there is no NPM command in the terminal.  So this answer is not working, as the referenced plugin is deprecated.

Answer (score 54):

You can run npm commands directly in terminal (ctrl + `). Make sure that terminal has cmd.exe as the shell selected.

You can default cmd.exe as your shell by following these steps.

1. ctrl+Shift+p
2. Type > Terminal: Select Default Profile + Enter

   [older VSCode versions] Type > Select Default Shell + Enter
3. Select > Command Prompt ...cmd.exe
4. Restart VS Code.

Comment: even though I've installed several exenstions now, which I though would force `npm` to come along for the ride.. this tip didn't work for me. All I got: `'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. `

Comment: Ok.. I don't even have Node.js installed. [Per this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-tutorial) I'm realizing that's my first step, as it's not automatically installed w/VS Code

Comment: I thought I would have node already because I have VS 2022 installed with the node workload installed. Not sure why I have to install it again.

Comment: Node isn't a mandatory add-on for Visual Studio. But you can still verify if you have node installed in you PC by using this command in CMD > node -v

Comment: "Select default shell" is not available as of VS Code 1.8

Comment: Thanks for letting know, I have updated the latest option here now.

Answer (score 41):

There might be a chance that you have install node.js while your visual studio code was open.
Once node.js is install successfully, Simply close the VS Code and Start it again. It will work.
Thank you

Comment: **NOTE** `restart the application` not `reload window`. At least as of VSC 1.31.1, this is true. Though this answer states `restart the application` I expected to be able to get this fixed through a `reload window`.

Comment: Note: "close the VS Code" means closing ALL windows :)

Comment: This was my problem. It is resolved now. Thank you!

Answer (score 16):

On Win10 I had to run VSCode as administrator to npm commands work.

Comment: this worked! lol

Comment: Thanks, This works for Windows 11 too.

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is to add args to the integrated terminal within 'User Settings' window.

Follow this steps below to do that:

1. List item
2. Go to 'User Settings'
3. Search for setting named - "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows"
4. Edit this setting by copying it to the right side.
5. Add the following arg value = "/k nodevars.bat", e.g. `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/k nodevars.bat"],`
6. Make sure that the setting named "terminal.integrated.shell.windows" is set to the value - "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe". If not then do that.
7. Open new Terminal.

Good luck

Answer (score 9):

One reason might be if you install the node after starting the vs code,as vs code terminal integrated or external takes the path value which was at the time of starting the vs code and gives you error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable
>   program or batch file.

A simple restart of vs code will solve the issue.

Answer (score 8):

I installed npm after Visual studio code, closed all visual studio instances and opened again and it started working.

Comment: This is a not a fix/relevant suggestion. Please refactor your answer.

Answer (score 6):

1. Edit user setting file `settings.json`.

   - Settings > Search for `settings.json` > Edit in `settings.json`

   or

   - Run > type `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
2. Copy this code
       

       `{
       "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
       "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/k nodevars.bat"]
   }`
3. Restart VS Code

Answer (score 5):

To install npm on VS Code:

1. Click Ctrl+P
2. Write ext install npm script runner
3. On the results list look for npm 'npm commands for VS Code'.  This npm manages commands.  Click Install, then Reload VS Code to save changes
4. Restart VS Code
5. On the Integrated Terminal, Run 'npm install'

Comment: As for now, date 2018-08-20, the latest version is 0.3.5

Comment: does not work for me !  VSCode Terminal keeps saying `bash: np: command not found`. What do you suggest ? Thanks for any help on this. (Hint: My npm cmds work well under the Mac Terminal. But they absolutely do not work under VSCode Terminal - not even after having followed your steps above.) I try to run Angular cmds such as `np version` and they do not work in VSCode Terminal. And I am on Mac. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3):

Same thing was happening to me after I installed **Node.js**. Node and npm was recognized in PowerShell and Command Prompt but not in VS Code. I fixed it by adding the Node.js install path to the system's environment `PATH` variable. The node.js install path on my system was:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

Where I find the `node.exe` that is needed. The user's `PATH` variable already had the Node.js install path but for some reason VS Code needs the Node.js install path in the system's `PATH` variables.

Windows 10 instructions:

1. Windows key and type "environment"
2. Select "Edit the system environment variables"
3. Click button labelled "Environment Variables..."
4. In "System variables" section edit the "Path" variable
5. Add Node.js install path to the list (C:\Program Files\nodejs)

The other answers were great but this is another way to fix it that worked for me without needing to install stuff, run as admin, or change the default settings.

Answer (score 2):

`VSCode User Setup` is a new installer which installs VSCode and its dependencies in directories which don't require system-level / administrator permissions to modify. This is because New VSCode runs with user privileges. Your Nodejs installation added npm's path as System variable which VSCode cannot read.

> Adding NPM path to Path variable in the User variable, you will be able to run NPM from the integrated command line.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you exit out of the existing terminal window. It will try to recover it and even though you may have closed out of VS Code you want to close the terminal window *as well*

Answer (score 1):

Try to install PowerShell extension provided by VS code.

[image: PowerShell Extension]

After install click on PowerShell and It will start new PowerShell Console where you can run all script

[image: PowerShell Console]

Answer (score 1):

One from this two can help:

A) After you installed NodeJS, and restarted VScode, but still not getting `npm` to work, then idelete the opened terminal in VSCode with 'recycle' icon and try to create a new instance of terminal. From that moment and onwards, NPM should be working

B) If that doesn't help, then open up the prompt (`Ctrl+P`) and type `>Terminal>Create terminal (with profile)` and create 'cmd/powershell' based terminal. Afterwards, npm should be working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, anyone still ends up here, and couldn't resolve the problem, Here is how to fix it.

1. Check the default terminal in VS Code (ctrl+ ~). It should be **cmd** and not **Powershell**.

   If it is Powershell, go to settings > features > Terminal › Integrated ›
   Default Profile: Windows. And select **Command Prompt**.
   Or in search settings type 'default profile', and select **Command Prompt**.
2. Install VS Code extension - **npm script runner** (npm support for VS Code by Microsoft).
   Click on extensions marketplace (ctrl + shift + x).
   Type> npm script runner > install

After these steps, npm should be working from VS Code terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Download Node.js from the link [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
Install and then Then restart

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension available, `npm Script runner`. I have not tried it myself, though.

Comment: If you have not tried this extension, why are you recommending it?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to some of the answers suggested above, if you have powershell installed, you can invoke that directly as your terminal.  That is edit the corresponding `setting.json` value as follows:

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
```

I find this works well as the environment is correctly configured.

Answer (score 0):

Open standard terminal ctrl+p and paste this command

```
npm i script-runner
```

> Need to see this logs     npm should be run outside of the node repl,
>   in your normal shell. (Press Control-D to exit.)
>
> > (To exit, press ^C again or type .exit)
>
> C:\DW\Examples\Ang.Crud>npm i script-runner npm WARN saveError ENOENT:
>   no such file or directory, open 'C:\DW\Examples\Ang.Crud\package.json'
>   npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit
>   this file.  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\DW\Examples\Ang.Crud\package.json' npm WARN Ang.Crud No
>   description npm WARN Ang.Crud No repository field. npm WARN Ang.Crud
>   No README data npm WARN Ang.Crud No license field.
>
> - script-runner@0.1.8 added 7 packages from 5 contributors and audited 7 packages in 2.955s found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> Usage: npm
>
> where  is one of:
>       access, adduser, audit, bin, bugs, c, cache, ci, cit,
>       completion, config, create, ddp, dedupe, deprecate,
>       dist-tag, docs, doctor, edit, explore, get, help,
>       help-search, hook, i, init, install, install-test, it, link,
>       list, ln, login, logout, ls, outdated, owner, pack, ping,
>       prefix, profile, prune, publish, rb, rebuild, repo, restart,
>       root, run, run-script, s, se, search, set, shrinkwrap, star,
>       stars, start, stop, t, team, test, token, tst, un,
>       uninstall, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v, version, view,
>       whoami
>
> npm  -h  quick help on  npm -l            display
>   full usage info npm help    search for help on  npm help
>   npm      involved overview
>
> Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
>       C:\Users\fdc.npmrc or on the command line via: npm  --key value Config info can be viewed via: npm help config
>
> npm@6.4.1 C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm

Answer (score 0):

For me, this problem is fixed after installing the extension ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native snippets. I am using windows 10 and the latest version of VS Code, and a little interpreter icon occurred on the lower right of the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

**npm not works in Visual studio code** 
open vs code then **Ctrl+P -> type - ext install npm script runner** 
you have to choose one and install it. 
once installed **please close and open Visual studio code**
and go to vs code terminal and 
 **type npm start** and browser will start **http://localhost:3000**
Its working good. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my machine, after checking the path in environment variable. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal run ->
npm install script-runner

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont have your path variable set for npm on your machine. And typescript has nothing to do with this issue. VS Code is built on TypeScript for type checking when you're using JavaScript. But i'd suggest you to uninstall Node from your machine and re-install Node from here. Make sure you install the latest version of Node. Node comes with npm and it also sets the PATH_VARIABLE for terminal. In order to check if the path variable set or not , you can try this command `node --version` or `npm --version`.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do the following 3 steps to fix your issues:

1.Download Node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/).

2. Install it and then add the path  C:\Program Files\nodejs to your System variables.
3. Then restart your visual studio code editor.

Happy code